# Abstract Algebra 1 about permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutations

I have a question from exam and I really don't know how to solve it, and tried a lot.

Say I have a permutation $a=(1 6)(2 5 7)(3 8 4 9)$ so that $a \in S_9$ and I want to find how many permutations $b\in S_9$ exist that commute with $a$ with respect to the composition operation: $a\star b=b \star a$

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider, just for testing, $b=(124)(35)(6789)$ and compute
\begin{align}
b\star a\star b^{-1}
&=
(124)(35)(6789)(16)(257)(3849)(142)(35)(6987)\\
&=(1659)(27)(384)\\
&=\bigl(b(1)\,b(6)\bigr)\,
  \bigl(b(2)\,b(5)\,b(7)\bigr)\,
  \bigl(b(3)\,b(8)\,b(4)\,b(9)\bigr)
\end{align}

This holds in general (and you should be able to prove it): *if $b$ is any permutation in $S_9$, then $b\star a\star b^{-1}$ is the permutation obtained by applying $b$ to every element in the disjoint cycle decomposition of $a$*.

Now, $a\star b=b\star a$ is the same as $b\star a\star b^{-1}=a$.

Comment: I also thought that 
But that means that the answer to this a number of a forms?
mean 2*3*4?
I just was not sure.

Comment: @hedbisker Yes, that's the answer: $b$ must map each cycle of $a$ into itself, so you have two choices for the $2$-cycle, three for the $3$-cycle and four for the $4$-cycle.

Comment: OK thank you a lot :)

Comment: @hedbisker: Have you ever tried using a Combinatorial software like GAP? You can check the problem by it.

Comment: no where can i find this software?
this free?

Comment: @hedbisker http://www.gap-system.org

Answer (score 1):

Note that instead of computing the size of the centralizer $C_{S_9}(a)$ of $a$ directly you can compute the size of the conjugacy class $C_a$ of $a$, because $|C_a| |C_{S_9}(a)| = |S_9| = 9!$. But the conjugacy class of $a$ just consists of all the permutations of the form $(s_1,s_2)(s_3,s_4,s_5)(s_6,s_7,s_8,s_9)$ with $\{s_1,\dots,s_9\} = \{1,\dots, 9\}$, so this reduces your problem to a question of combinatorics, namely counting the number of permutations of this form.

Comment: you mean   9!/4! = |CS9(a)|  ? 
coz the all permutations of a its 24

Comment: It is the other way around. There are $9!/4!$ permutations conjugate to $a$. This is $|C_a|$ and so $|C_{S_9}(a)|= 9!/|C_a| = 24$ (as you already know).